# Should we unit test what method actually does, or what it should do?

Tags: unit-testing

The question might seem a bit weird, but i'll explain it.

Consider following:
We have a service `FirstNameValidator`, which i created for other developers so they have a consistent way to validate a person's first name. I want to test it, but because the full set of possible inputs is infinite (or very very big), i only test few cases:

```
Assert.IsTrue(FirstNameValidator.Validate("John"))
Assert.IsFalse(FirstNameValidator.Validate("$$123"))
```

I also have `LastNameValidator`, which is 99% identical, and i wrote a test for it too:

```
Assert.IsTrue(LastNameValidator.Validate("Doe"))
Assert.IsFalse(LastNameValidator.Validate("__%%"))
```

But later a new structure appeared - PersonName, which consists of first name and last name. We want to validate it too, so i create a PersonNameValidator. Obviously, for reusability i just call FirstNameValidator and LastNameValidator. Everything is fine till i want to write a test for it.

What should i test?

The fact that FirstNameValidator.Validate was actually called with correct argument?

Or i need to create few cases and test them?

That is actually the question - should we test what service is expected to do? It is expected to validate PersonName, how it does it we actually don't care. So we pass few valid and invalid inputs and expect corresponding return values.

Or, maybe, what it actually does? Like it actually just calls other validators, so test that (.net mocking framework allows it).

Comment: Related cross-site duplicates on SE.SE: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/288532/24993, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/234024/24993 (and probably others)

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should be acceptance criteria for a properly functioning unit of code...
they should test what the code *should* and *shouldn't* do, you will often find corner cases when you are writing tests.

If you refactor code, you often will have to refactor tests... This should be viewed as part of the original effort, and should bring glee to your soul as you have made the product and process an improvement of such magnitude.

of course if this is a library with outside (or internal, depending on company culture) consumers, you have documentation to consider before you are completely done.

edit: also those tests are pretty weak, you should have a definition of what is legal in each, and actually test inclusion and exclusion of at least all of the classes of glyphps... they can still use related code for testing... ie `isValidUsername(name,allowsSpace)` could work for both first name and whole name depending on if spaces are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You have formulated your question a bit strangely: Both options that you describe would test that the function behaves as it should - but in each case on a different level of granularity.  In one case you would test the behaviour based on the API that is available to a user of the function.  Whether and how the function implements its functionality with the help of other functions/components is not relevant.  In the second case you test the behaviour in isolation, including the way the function interacts with its dependended-on components.

On a general level it is not possible to say which is better - depending on the circumstances each option may be the best.  In general, isolating a piece of software requires usually more effort to implement the tests and makes the tests more fragile against implementation changes.  That means, going for isolation should only be done in situations where there are good reasons for it.  Before getting to your specific case, I will describe some situations where isolation is recommendable.

- With the original depended-on component (DOC), you may not be able to test everything you want.  Assume your code does error handling for the case the DOC returns an error code.  But, if the DOC can not easily be made to return an error code, you have difficulty to test your error handling.  In this case, if you double the DOC you could make the double return an error code, and thus also test your error handling.
- The DOC may have non-deterministic or system-specific behaviour.  Some examples are random number generators or date and time functions.  If this makes testing your functions difficult, it would be an argument to replace the DOC with some double, so you have control over what is provided to your functions.
- The DOC may require a very complex setup.  Imagine a complex data base or some complex xml document that needs to be provided.  For one thing, this can make your setup quite complicated, for another, your tests get fragile and will likely break if the DOC changes (think that the XML schema changes...).
- The setup of the DOC or the calls to the DOC are very time consuming (imagine reading data from a network connection, computing the next chess move, solving the TSP, ...).  Or, the use of the DOC prolongs compilation or linking significantly.  With a double you can possibly shorten the execution or build time significantly, which is the more interesting the more often you are executing / building the tests.
- You may not have a working version of the DOC - possibly the DOC is still under development and is not yet available.  Then, with doubles you can start testing nevertheless.
- The DOC may be immature, such that with the version you have your tests are instable.  In such a case it is likely that you lose trust in your test results and start ignoring failing tests.
- The DOC itself may have other dependencies which have some of the problems described above.

These criteria can help to come to an informed decision about whether isolation is necessary.  Considering your specific example: The way you have described the situation I get the impression that none of the above criteria is fulfilled.  Which for me would lead to the conclusion that I would not isolate the function `PersonNameValidator` from its DOCs `FirstNameValidator` and `LastNameValidator`.